# PostgreSQL remove char from column that endswith

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to remove the values in a column that ends with those char : "*8"

I've found them with:

```
    SELECT 
        "PIPPO"  
    FROM 
        "PLUTO"
    WHERE
    "PIPPO" LIKE '%*8'
```

is there a simple way to **remove** those ending characters with a query?

Comment: You can use Replace(PIPPO,'*8','')

Comment: @MukeshKalgude What about a column with '*8' in the middle of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE "PLUTO"
SET "PIPPO" = left("PIPPO", -2)
WHERE right("PIPPO", 2) = '*8';
```

The [`left()` and `right()` functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) return substrings from an input string. Use of a negative length value returns "everything but", so for a value of 'qwerty*8' `left("PIPPO", -2)` produces 'qwerty' and `right("PIPPO", 2)` produces '*8'. Note that this will be faster than working with the `LIKE` operator, except with an index on the expression.

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expression for your replace. it's powerful.

```
update test
set name = regexp_replace(name, '8$', '');
```

[Click to View Test Script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/83c7d2/2/0)

Comment: '$' in Regular Exp represents the end of a line. so '8$' matches the string with the end '8'.